# Non linear functions where the kernel is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

If $f:V\rightarrow V$ is linear function where $V$ is vectorial space over a field $F$, it is true that the $ker(f)$ is a subspace of $V$. My question is, is a there function where the kernel is a subspace but the function is not linear?

The $\text{sin}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ almost satisfies it, but unfortunately it fails on $\lambda\in F$ and $v\in\ker(\text{sin})$ then $\lambda v\in\ker(\text{sin})$ unless $F=\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $x \mapsto x^2 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. The kernel of this function is $\{0\}$, which is a subspace. But clearly the function is not linear.

Comment: That's it! If you allow me, is there any function that the kernel is not just the $0$ ? Thank you

Comment: @Glo Consider the function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x, y) = y^2$. The kernel is $\{(x, 0) : x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: uau wonderful and simple, thank you!